# Implementation of constrained optimization methods in TensorFlow?

Tags: optimization, tensorflow

I'm looking for something like the l_bfgs_b or tnc methods that exist in scipy.optimize. Has anyone seen implementations of these?

Answer (score 6):

You might have a look at [tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/ScipyOptimizerInterface). This lets you use Scipy optimizers on TensorFlow models directly.

Comment: Oh wow. Do these actually do the optimization on the GPU or is it somehow calling scipy externally​?

Comment: The model itself can certainly run on the GPU, but unfortunately there's going to be quite a bit of copying back and forth to the CPU for the optimization steps themselves (i.e. it's actually using the Scipy optimizer, it's not inserting it into the TensorFlow model). For some models (lots of computation, not too many parameters) it will work fine. For models which run in a couple of milliseconds on the GPU it's going to slow things down.

Comment: @AllenLavoie how to address the problem of combined constraint such as `a + b + c = 1`

Comment: `equalities=[a + b + c - 1.]`? Assuming `a`, `b`, `c`, are `Tensor`s.